# ReactJS - Overwrite array if same keys

Tags: reactjs, arrays, setstate

I want to overwrite the array if the keys are the same. And push if keys are different.
From this:

```
const fieldData = [
 {
    "field_1": { 
        "value": "oldValue" 
    },
    "field_2": { 
         "value": "oldValue" 
    }
  }
];

const [data, setData] = useState(fieldData);

const pushData = (newData) => {
  setData(current => [...current, newData]);
}
```

The result if the keys are the same:

```
 {
    "field_1": { 
        "value": "newValue" 
    },
    "field_2": { 
         "value": "oldValue" 
    }
  }
```

The result if the keys are diffrent:

```
 {
    "field_1": { 
        "value": "newValue" 
    },
    "field_2": { 
         "value": "oldValue" 
    },
    "field_3": { 
         "value": "newValue Field 3" 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to work with a different data structure.
Change your array and work with a dictionary.

```
const fieldData =  {
    "field_1": { 
        "value": "oldValue" 
    },
    "field_2": { 
         "value": "oldValue" 
    }
  }

const [data, setData] = useState(fieldData);

const pushData = (newData) => {
  setData(current => ({...current,...newData}));
}
```

In this case, if you have a new [key, value] it will be added to your object. Otherwise the value will be overridden